# Algorithm for number masking/encryption

Tags: php

I have no idea how to do this in PHP. The following is what I need to achieve:

1. Mask a **n** digit number with alpha numeric value
2. Generated code should be of length 9
3. Code must be unique
4. Generate same code for a particular number
5. Should be able to decode to original number

Comment: What do you mean by "masking a number"? Are you looking for some kind of encryption scheme (seems like it, due to point 6)? If so, points 2 and 6 become contradictory because of the Pigeon Hole Principle.

Comment: Yes, some kind of an encryption scheme

Comment: Then, as I mentioned, you will hit upon a problem due to the [Pigeon Hole Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle).